# What's wrong with my -replace operator?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to change the VM paths of all my VMS to move them to a different mount point:

```
$oldmount = "C:\RAID-5"
$newmount = "D:"

$drives = Get-VM | Get-VMHardDiskDrive
foreach ($drive in $drives)
{
    $path = $drive.path
    $path -replace $oldmount, $newmount     # just show what the new path will look like
}
```

If I run the above script I get a load of these errors:

```
The regular expression pattern C:\RAID-5 is not valid.
At C:\Users\mark\Documents\ChangeAllVMDrives.ps1:8 char:5
+     $path -replace $oldmount, $newmount
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\RAID-5:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-replace` is using *regular expressions* thus you have to **escape** it using `[regex]::Escape()`:

```
# ....
 $path -replace [regex]::Escape($oldmount), $newmount     # just show what the new path will look like
```

Or you can use the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) string class method `Replace()`:

```
$path.Replace($oldmount, $newmount)
```